# How Two root nodes can share common child nodes?

Tags: angular, angular-material, treeview, angular-tree-component

We are currently exploring the [angular tree view component](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs).

and we need to achieve the below scenario.

[image]

On the drag and drop, Layer 4 and Layer 1 are going to share common children, we can merge the children, but in UI perspective, we need to change the tree-node-expander should looks like in the above image.

Is It possible with angular-tree-view component?